# AngularJS and jQuery UI Layout compatibility

Tags: angularjs, jquery-ui-layout

I'm struggling to get a very basic layout using jQuery UI Layout (downloaded from [here](http://layout.jquery-dev.com/)).

Following is the `ng-include`ed page:

```
<div id="Main_Working_Page" ng-controller="Main_Working_Page_Controller" style="height:100%;">

    <div id="Muti_Panel" style="height:100%">

        <div class="ui-layout-north">
            This is the north pane
        </div>
        
        <div class="ui-layout-west">
            This is the north west
        </div>
        
        <div id="tabs-center" class="ui-layout-center no-scrollbar add-padding grey">
            
            This is the central panel
            
        </div>
 
    </div>
    
</div>
```

and here is the controller for this page:

```
MyApp.controller('Main_Working_Page_Controller' , ['$rootScope' , '$scope' ,  'DB_Services' , function( $rootScope , $scope , DB_Services) {
    
    console.log(">>> Started Main_Working_Page_Controller") ;

    var Main_Page_Layout = $("#Muti_Panel").layout(
        {
            defaults: {
                fxName              :   "slide"     ,
                fxSpeed             :   "slow"      ,
                spacing_closed      :   14          ,
                initClosed          :   false       ,
                size                :   "200"       ,
                spacing_open        :   6           ,
                spacing_closed      :   6 
            }    ,
            
            applyDefaultStyles      :   true        ,

            north: {
                fxName              :   "slide"     ,
                spacing_closed      :   8           ,
                togglerLength_closed:   "100%"      ,
                closable            :   true        ,
                resizable           :   true        ,
                slidable            :   true        ,
                initClosed          :   false       ,
                initHidden          :   false       ,
                size                :   100         ,
                autoResize          :   false

            }    ,
            south: {
                fxName              :   "slide"     ,
                spacing_closed      :   8           ,
                togglerLength_closed:   "100%"      ,
                closable            :   true        ,
                resizable           :   true        ,
                slidable            :   true        ,
                initClosed          :   false       ,
                initHidden          :   false       ,
                size                :   100         ,
                autoResize          :   false 
            }    ,
            east: {
                fxName              :   "slide"     ,
                spacing_closed      :   15          ,
                togglerLength_closed:   "100%"      ,
                closable            :   true        ,
                resizable           :   true        ,
                slidable            :   true        ,
                initClosed          :   false       ,
                initHidden          :   false       ,
                size                :   300         ,
                autoResize          :   false
            }    ,
            center: {
                fxName              :   "slide"     ,
                closable            :   false       ,
                size                :   300
            }
        }
    ) ;
    
    Main_Page_Layout.resizeAll() ;
    
}]) ;
```

The page appears blank (nothing at all!!!) and the only way to see something is to enter the debug mode in Chrome and change some of the `...location:absolute...` into `...location:relative...`. When doing that, the layout is still far from what I want, but at least is visible.

Either I am missing something really fundamental in the way UI Layout needs to be used or there is a conflict with AngularJS.

Comment: *"[...] there is a conflict with AngularJS"* => Well, you should probably not use a jQuery library with AngularJS. So if you can change, change.

Comment: If you could provide a plunker of fiddle, i could help you with the root cause

Comment: Not quite @Mistalis. There are plenty of site all around the world using both (AngularJS and JQuery), including other projects I've done in the past with no issues at all. My question is not about **JQuery** but **JQuery UI Layout**.

Comment: @Pramod_Para, thanks. It would not be simple for me since there are quite many libraries included (JQuery, Bootstrap, AngularJS) and, must shamefully confess, I never created a plunker of fiddler. If you have specific things in your mind to check, I can perform the checks and tell you what the results are. Can you?

Comment: We have used a lot of jquery in project along with angularJS, so using both should not be an issue

Comment: @Pramod_Para agree in reference to JQuery. My question was directed to **JQuery UI Layout** set of libraries.